# Unexpected results in shell script when executed from a double click in GUI

Tags: bash, shell

I've created a shell script on my mac that I want to eventually fire from a double click of it's icon. The script takes the present working directory of the file, looks for a particular folder name, and then opens an afp connection to a matching folder on one of my company's servers.

The script fires successfully when executed from my terminal. Here's the script with the IP address substituted with "X"s:

```
#!/bin/bash

clientCode=$(pwd | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "/" } ; { print $4 }')
# echo $clientCode

open afp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/Storage/Clients/$clientCode
```

As I said, this fires successfully when using the `./openOnServer.sh` command from my terminal, but when I make the file executable and modify it's properties to open the shell with terminal the `clientCode` variable no longer populates.

I've also tried just writing the present working directory to the variable and `echo`-ing that out. Again, it works when I fire it from my terminal but does not work when executing the script from the icon double click.

Is there a way of getting this to work from a double click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a mac, but this sounds similar to the usual problems when running programs from cron. In particular, your environment variables are completely different (but have a lot of influence on script operation). My guess is that your `PATH` is different when started via GUI.

Try setting `PATH` in your script, either with a colon separated list, or, if it's available on your mac, with `getconf`:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)   # Assigns system default PATH.
 # rest of script
```

A different idea: avoid forking a command and get at the fourth PWD component using only the shell

```
 IFS=/
 set -- "$PWD"
 open "afp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/Storage/Clients/$4"
```

If this fails, you need to know exactly *what* is failing by inspecting stdout and stderr. You could to this with

```
 exec >/tmp/stdout 2>/tmp/stderr
```

at the top of the script. Run via GUI. Look at `/tmp/std{out,err}`. Any clues there? My guess would be that `PWD` is different in GUIs and you don't even have a third component because the script is run in, say, a sandbox directory like `/tmp/guiexec.XXXX`.

Comment: Good idea. I followed your logic and found that the command `/usr/bin/getconf PATH` definitely does work on my mac. I tried adding just the text you gave to my shell and it still doesn't work from the icon dclick. Following your logic I tried giving the full path to each of my commands `clientCode=$(/bin/pwd | /usr/local/bin/awk 'BEGIN { FS = "/" } ; { print $4 }')` though that did not make a difference either from the dclick :/

Comment: I found some additional information. I changed the variable declaration to `clientCode=$(/bin/pwd)` (the only difference between this and what I tried before was including the full path). I then tried executing from the full path and it told me my present working directory was actually the root of my home folder. it must be happening because when the double click happens it executes in a sub shell (maybe?) that fires from my home. Is there a way of using the shell script's `pwd` result that doesn't fire in a sub shell, i.e. not `$(/bin/pwd)`?

Comment: No, programs forked in `$()` run in the same directory. But programs started from the GUI may have a different working directory from the one you expect. What do you expect `$4` to be exactly? A username?

Comment: It's supposed to be a folder name. I explain it in a [reply on a different answer on this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208179/unexpected-results-in-shell-script-when-executed-from-a-double-click-in-gui/#comment-33717567).

Comment: Okay, I understand better now. The value of PWD has absolutely nothing to do with the full path of the script. They are completely independent so deriving the script directory from PWD is getting you nowhere. Instead, look for a way to pass an argument to the script when clicked. (On Windows you can pass options and arguments when you modify an icon's properties; Can a mac do the same?).

Comment: Ah ok good to know. Just to be sure I understand, the reason why the script works when fired from the terminal is because it's using the `pwd` value of the terminal shell, not the shell script itself so when I double click the file from the GUI, the terminal window it opens and fires the script is not necessarily opening from the scripts directory. I just tried it out and that was true; the shell that fires `pwd` is definitely my user's root folder. I'll look into how I could pass the script's directory on a double click. I have some ideas to go off of now. Thanks!

Comment: Right; if you want to know which directory the GUI starts your script in, add `echo $PWD > /tmp/pwd`, or better yet, inspect the whole environment with `set > /tmp/environment`. Maybe you'll find what you need in some other variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "present working directory", do you mean the directory where the script lives?

If yes, change

```
clientCode=$(pwd | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "/" } ; { print $4 }')
```

to

```
clientCode=$(basename "$(dirname "$0")")
```

I'm assuming you want the last dir name, for example "/foo/bar/baz/qux/openOnServer.sh" that you want "clientCode=qux"

---

another crack:

```
dir=$(cd -- "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd -P)
clientCode=$(basename "$dir")
```

Comment: Yeah, the directory that all of my client files are in is `/Volumes/Secure/XXX/` where `XXX` is the client code. I'm wanting to be able to put this shell script anywhere in one of the subfolders within one of the client code folders so that when I double click the file it opens the matching folder on our storage server. All I would need to grab is that code which will always be the directory name 3 levels in.

Comment: Also, I tried `clientCode=$(basename "$(dirname "$0")")` and it just returned `.` which seems correct, it's denoting the present directory, but it's not giving the directory name.

Comment: When you double click the icon, what's in `$0`? can you determine that?

Comment: Ah, when I `echo` or `say` the variable `$0` it shows me `./openCurrentClientFolderOnServer.sh`which is the name of my shell script. It's like it only gives the relative path, not the full path. :/